# Scaladoc tag for HTTP request body?

Tags: scala, playframework, scaladoc

I am using Play2 with Scala and I would like to write information about the body of the request in the endpoint Scaladoc.

```
/**
  * Replaces images for a given user.
  *
  * @param id The user id
  * @body a multipart HTTP body with the image files   <-- NO GOOD
  * @return
  */
def replaceImages(id: String) = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) {
    ...
}
```

I couldn't find an appropriate tag in the [Scaladoc's documentation](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tags+and+Annotations). What would be the appropriate tag?